# SLES 11 update glibc using rpm

Tags: rpm, suse, glibc

I'm trying to upgrade glibc but I'm getting failed dependencies however it also says the dependencies is (installed)? Should I run it with ignore all dependencies?

SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)

```
    localhost:~ # rpm -U glibc-2.14.1-14.28.3.x86_64.rpm 
warning: glibc-2.14.1-14.28.3.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID b5daf13d
error: Failed dependencies:
        glibc = 2.11.1 is needed by (installed) glibc-locale-2.11.1-0.17.4.x86_64
        glibc = 2.11.1 is needed by (installed) glibc-devel-2.11.1-0.17.4.x86_64
```

Comment: I just checked and it looks like the rpm I downloaded is for SLES 12. There isn't a 2.14 glibc for SLES11. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Never install packages with rpm directly. Use **`zypper`**.
And where you get that rpm .. On SLE11 is **glibc-2.11.x** and on SLE12 is **glibc-2.19.x**

Plus replacing this low level system package by another, unknown source version **BROKE** your system.